# How to change Surface View Height in Xamarin.Android?

Tags: android, camera, xamarin.android, surfaceview

My layout code.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:showIn="@layout/Main">
<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/camera_ll"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:weightSum="100"
    android:orientation="vertical">
    <FrameLayout
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:id="@+id/frameLayout"
        android:layout_weight="90" />
    <Button
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:id="@+id/btn_capture"
        android:text="Scan Answer Sheet"
        fontPath="Fonts/Verb-Semibold.otf"
        android:textColor="@android:color/white"
        android:background="@drawable/bttn_green"
        android:layout_weight="10" />
     </LinearLayout>
  </RelativeLayout>
```

My Java code is this.

```
    public class CameraPreview : Activity, Android.Hardware.Camera.IPictureCallback, Android.Hardware.Camera.IPreviewCallback, Android.Hardware.Camera.IShutterCallback
{
    String PICTURE_FILENAME = "picture.jpg";
    Preview mPreview;
    Camera mCamera;
    int numberOfCameras;
    int cameraCurrentlyLocked;

    // The first rear facing camera
    int defaultCameraId;
    FrameLayout frameLayout;
    Button btn_capture;
    protected override void OnCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        base.OnCreate(savedInstanceState);

        // Hide the window title and go fullscreen.
        RequestWindowFeature(WindowFeatures.NoTitle);
        Window.AddFlags(WindowManagerFlags.Fullscreen);

        // Create our Preview view and set it as the content of our activity.

        SetContentView(Resource.Layout.CameraPriview);
        frameLayout = FindViewById<FrameLayout>(Resource.Id.frameLayout);
        btn_capture = FindViewById<Button>(Resource.Id.btn_capture);
        mPreview = new Preview(this, frameLayout);
        frameLayout.AddView(mPreview);
        btn_capture.Click += TakeAPicture;
        // Find the total number of cameras available
        numberOfCameras = Camera.NumberOfCameras;

        // Find the ID of the default camera
        Camera.CameraInfo cameraInfo = new Camera.CameraInfo();
        for (int i = 0; i < numberOfCameras; i++)
        {
            Camera.GetCameraInfo(i, cameraInfo);
            if (cameraInfo.Facing == CameraFacing.Back)
            {
                defaultCameraId = i;
            }
        }
    }
    private void TakeAPicture(object sender, EventArgs eventArgs)
    {

        Android.Hardware.Camera.Parameters p = mCamera.GetParameters();
        p.PictureFormat = Android.Graphics.ImageFormatType.Jpeg;
        mCamera.SetParameters(p);
        mCamera.TakePicture(this, this, this);

    }
    void Camera.IPictureCallback.OnPictureTaken(byte[] data, Android.Hardware.Camera camera)
    {
        FileOutputStream outStream = null;
        File dataDir = Android.OS.Environment.ExternalStorageDirectory;
        if (data != null)
        {
            try
            {
                outStream = new FileOutputStream(dataDir + "/" + PICTURE_FILENAME);
                outStream.Write(data);
                outStream.Close();
            }
            catch (FileNotFoundException e)
            {
                System.Console.Out.WriteLine(e.Message);
            }
            catch (IOException ie)
            {
                System.Console.Out.WriteLine(ie.Message);
            }
        }
    }

    void Camera.IPreviewCallback.OnPreviewFrame(byte[] b, Android.Hardware.Camera c)
    {

    }

    void Camera.IShutterCallback.OnShutter()
    {

    }
    protected override void OnResume()
    {
        base.OnResume();

        // Open the default i.e. the first rear facing camera.
        mCamera = Camera.Open();
        cameraCurrentlyLocked = defaultCameraId;
        mPreview.PreviewCamera = mCamera;
        mCamera.SetDisplayOrientation(90);



    }


    protected override void OnPause()
    {
        base.OnPause();

        // Because the Camera object is a shared resource, it's very
        // important to release it when the activity is paused.
        if (mCamera != null)
        {
            mPreview.PreviewCamera = null;
            mCamera.Release();
            mCamera = null;
        }
    }

    public override bool OnCreateOptionsMenu(IMenu menu)
    {
        // Inflate our menu which can gather user input for switching camera
        //MenuInflater.Inflate(Resource.Menu.camera_menu, menu);
        return true;
    }


}
```

Surface View Code.

```
  class Preview : ViewGroup, ISurfaceHolderCallback
{
    string TAG = "Preview";
    FrameLayout f;
    SurfaceView mSurfaceView;
    ISurfaceHolder mHolder;
    Camera.Size mPreviewSize;
    IList<Camera.Size> mSupportedPreviewSizes;
    Camera _camera;

    public Camera PreviewCamera
    {
        get { return _camera; }
        set
        {
            _camera = value;
            if (_camera != null)
            {
                mSupportedPreviewSizes = PreviewCamera.GetParameters().SupportedPreviewSizes;
                RequestLayout();
            }
        }
    }

    public Preview(Context context, FrameLayout f) : base(context)
    {
        this.f = f;
        mSurfaceView = new SurfaceView(context);
        AddView(mSurfaceView);

        // Install a SurfaceHolder.Callback so we get notified when the
        // underlying surface is created and destroyed.
        mHolder = mSurfaceView.Holder;
        mHolder.AddCallback(this);
        mHolder.SetType(SurfaceType.PushBuffers);

    }

    public void SwitchCamera(Camera camera)
    {
        PreviewCamera = camera;

        try
        {
            camera.SetPreviewDisplay(mHolder);
        }
        catch (Java.IO.IOException exception)
        {
            Log.Error(TAG, "IOException caused by setPreviewDisplay()", exception);
        }

        Camera.Parameters parameters = camera.GetParameters();
        parameters.SetPreviewSize(mPreviewSize.Width, mPreviewSize.Height);

        RequestLayout();

        camera.SetParameters(parameters);
    }

    protected override void OnMeasure(int widthMeasureSpec, int heightMeasureSpec)
    {
        // We purposely disregard child measurements because act as a
        // wrapper to a SurfaceView that centers the camera preview instead
        // of stretching it.
        int width = ResolveSize(SuggestedMinimumWidth, widthMeasureSpec);
        int height = ResolveSize(SuggestedMinimumHeight, heightMeasureSpec);
        SetMeasuredDimension(width, height);

        if (mSupportedPreviewSizes != null)
        {
           mPreviewSize = GetOptimalPreviewSize(mSupportedPreviewSizes, width, height);
        }
    }

    protected override void OnLayout(bool changed, int l, int t, int r, int b)
    {
        if (changed && ChildCount > 0)
        {
            View child = GetChildAt(0);

            int width = r - l;
            int height = b - t;

            int previewWidth = width;
            int previewHeight = height;
            if (mPreviewSize != null)
            {
                previewWidth = mPreviewSize.Width;
                previewHeight = mPreviewSize.Height;
            }

            // Center the child SurfaceView within the parent.
            if (width * previewHeight > height * previewWidth)
            {
                int scaledChildWidth = previewWidth * height / previewHeight;
                child.Layout((width - scaledChildWidth) / 2, 0,
                             (width + scaledChildWidth) / 2, height);
            }
            else
            {
                int scaledChildHeight = previewHeight * width / previewWidth;
                child.Layout(0, (height - scaledChildHeight) / 2,
                             width, (height + scaledChildHeight) / 2);
            }
        }
    }

    public void SurfaceCreated(ISurfaceHolder holder)
    {
        // The Surface has been created, acquire the camera and tell it where
        // to draw.
        try
        {
            if (PreviewCamera != null)
            {

                PreviewCamera.SetPreviewDisplay(holder);

            }
        }
        catch (Java.IO.IOException exception)
        {
            Log.Error(TAG, "IOException caused by setPreviewDisplay()", exception);
        }
    }

    public void SurfaceDestroyed(ISurfaceHolder holder)
    {
        // Surface will be destroyed when we return, so stop the preview.
        if (PreviewCamera != null)
        {
            PreviewCamera.StopPreview();
        }
    }

    private Camera.Size GetOptimalPreviewSize(IList<Camera.Size> sizes, int w, int h)
    {
        const double ASPECT_TOLERANCE = 0.1;
        double targetRatio = (double)w / h;

        if (sizes == null)
            return null;

        Camera.Size optimalSize = null;
        double minDiff = Double.MaxValue;

        int targetHeight = h;

        // Try to find an size match aspect ratio and size
        foreach (Camera.Size size in sizes)
        {
            double ratio = (double)size.Width / size.Height;

            if (Math.Abs(ratio - targetRatio) > ASPECT_TOLERANCE)
                continue;

            if (Math.Abs(size.Height - targetHeight) < minDiff)
            {
                optimalSize = size;
                minDiff = Math.Abs(size.Height - targetHeight);
            }
        }

        // Cannot find the one match the aspect ratio, ignore the requirement
        if (optimalSize == null)
        {
            minDiff = Double.MaxValue;
            foreach (Camera.Size size in sizes)
            {
                if (Math.Abs(size.Height - targetHeight) < minDiff)
                {
                    optimalSize = size;
                    minDiff = Math.Abs(size.Height - targetHeight);
                }
            }
        }


        return optimalSize;
    }

    public void SurfaceChanged(ISurfaceHolder holder, Android.Graphics.Format format, int w, int h)
    {
        // Now that the size is known, set up the camera parameters and begin
        // the preview.
        Camera.Parameters parameters = PreviewCamera.GetParameters();
        parameters.SetPreviewSize(mPreviewSize.Width, mPreviewSize.Height);
        RequestLayout();

        PreviewCamera.SetParameters(parameters);
        PreviewCamera.StartPreview();
    }


}
```

Output:

[image]

Now i want to increase the camera height to fill all available space but nothing working for me. If anyone know the solution please help thanks.

Comment: Which android API level are you targeting?

Comment: i'm testing on KitKat (4.4.4) and target up to latest

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Now i want to increase the camera height to fill all available space but nothing working for me. If anyone know the solution please help thanks.

The setting codes of the preview Size lies in `Preview`'s `OnLayout` method:

```
protected override void OnLayout(bool changed, int l, int t, int r, int b)
{
    if (changed && ChildCount > 0)
    {
        View child = GetChildAt(0);

        int width = r - l;
        int height = b - t;

        int previewWidth = width;
        int previewHeight = height;
        if (mPreviewSize != null)
        {
            previewWidth = mPreviewSize.Width;
            previewHeight = mPreviewSize.Height;
        }

        // Center the child SurfaceView within the parent.
        if (width * previewHeight > height * previewWidth)
        {
            int scaledChildWidth = previewWidth * height / previewHeight;
            child.Layout((width - scaledChildWidth) / 2, 0,
                         (width + scaledChildWidth) / 2, height);
        }
        else
        {
            int scaledChildHeight = previewHeight * width / previewWidth;
            child.Layout(0, (height - scaledChildHeight) / 2,
                         width, (height + scaledChildHeight) / 2);
        }
    }
}
```

Here I don't get the codes' meaning. But by `child.Layout(0, (height - scaledChildHeight) / 2,width, (height + scaledChildHeight) / 2);`, you are decreasing the top boundary and bottom boundary of the preview window to  `(height - scaledChildHeight) / 2` and `(height + scaledChildHeight) / 2)`.

So to to increase the camera height to fill all available space you need to modify this code snippet.
For Example:

```
int LeftBoundary=0,TopBoundary=0;
int RightBoundary=r,BottomBoundary=b;
child.Layout(LeftBoundary,TopBoundary,RightBoundary,BottomBoundary));
```

Comment: Thanks @Elvis Xia - MSFT now its working with your help :)

Comment: my above code is working good with 4.4.4 but on Marshmallow 6.0.1 i'm getting black screen can you guide me about that?